# Forward/pass through UIGesture (swipe) to sibling view

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Let's assume the following setup:

[image]

There is a horizontal-only scrolling, transparent `UIScrollView`(rectangle with blueish background and red border) and a infinite number of `UIImageView` instances (reddish squares) being subviews of the same `UIView` (*`self.view`*).

The `UIScrollView` is being brought to front by

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollView]
```

in the containing `UIViewController`.

The following shall be achieved: The `UIScrollView` should receive the left/right swipe gestures to scroll horizontally, whereas the `UIImageViews` covert by the `UIScrollView` should receive swipe gestures with direction up/down, which are added as follows:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeUpGestureHandler:)];
swipeUpGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];
```

This works when the `UIImageView` is not covered by the `UIScrollView`, but obviously does not work when the `UIScrollView` is in front of said views.

To summarize, the `UIScrollView` should *forward* the up/down swipe event / gesture to the specific underlying `UIImageView`, but still receive the regular left/right swipe event / gesture for horizontal scrolling.

From what I read in the documentation it would be easy to solve if the `UIImageViews` would be contained inside the `UIScrollView` - however, that is not possible in this setup, and I'm pretty sure there has to be a solution to solve this problem.

Any hints are appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for this issue. While I was unable to forward the swipe up/down gestures to the image views behind the scrollview, I've now added gesture recognisers with direction up/down to the scrollview. In the gesture recognisers actions, I determine the point of the gesture within the window and hittest the window's first view for these point with a nil event. In the custom scrollview, I overwrote the hittest message to return NO with an empty event so the appropriate imageview would eventually be identifier. Once I got the imageview lying behind the scrollview at the point of the gesture, I was able to perform the appropriate action on my imageview.

I'm not sure whether this is the finest solution for this issue, however I wasn't able to build a better one after hours of investigation and experimenting. This setup might be a bit unusual and therefor tricky. Your input is still appreciated in case you have anything to add.